# What can cause fop intermittent java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/fop-page-0.ser error

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

We have a system running a very old version (0.20.5) of fop.
This has been working fine for many years, t## Heading ##he last 3 months we started seeing intermittent xml to pdf transform errors .

```
Mar 27, 2017 3:00:26 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
SEVERE: Error while deserializing page 1. Reason:    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/fop-page-0.ser (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/fop-page-0.ser (No such file or directory)
```

If we re-run the same transform it works without errors.
I advised upgrading fop to a recent version but I found nothing in the release notes https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/changes.html regarding this.

Is this a known issue, was it solved in a fop release ?

What can cause this ?

- AFAIK No changes related to fop have been made.
- The workload has increased, my guess is an issue with concurrent transforms

Comment: Can you post the full call to fop? Could you try running separate instances with different TMP or TMPDIR environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stefan Hegny for pointing me in the right direction. In our more recent versions of the fop script this was fixed by creating a temporary temp directory each time the script is executed.

To achieve this I added following 2 lines

```
FOP_TEMP=$(mktemp -d)
FOP_OPTS="$FOP_OPTS -Djava.io.tmp=$FOP_TEMP"
```

before the exiting java command line

```
$JAVACMD -classpath "$LOCALCLASSPATH" -Djava.awt.headless=true $FOP_OPTS org.apache.fop.apps.Fop "$@"
```

and

```
rmdir $FOP_TEMP
```

at the end to cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Carl, 
thanks for this solution. We had the same problem with fop-1.1, but to solve this, we had to use the property: java.io.tmpdir. We changed the line to:
FOP_OPTS="$FOP_OPTS -Djava.io.tmp=$FOP_TEMP -Djava.io.tmpdir=$FOP_TEMP"

Recent versions of FOP (2.0+) generate their own temp directories.